# getting facebook hash key error in cordova facebook connect

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I am getting facebook hash key problem for facebook applicxation in cordova facebook connect.
Application is working fine if it does not have the facebook application on mobile or emulator. But with faceboiok application it shopws the hash key error.[image]

I deleted application created new application all steps i did right but stll it showing the old hash key which is not exist over there. The hash key which is showing in the image is not present in app settings in facebook app.
from last two hours i am stucked on this problem.
Wihout facebook application its not detecting my facebook profile when sign in with facebook.

[image]
[image]
[image]

So its not able to recognize the my facebook profile. Thats why i am not able to fetch the facebook user details and not able to enter in to application.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that gave me the same error:

It turned out that I was using the 32bit version of OpenSSL (openssl-0.9.8e_WIN32) instead of the 64 bit one (openssl-0.9.8e_X64) to create my key hash, and it was creating an incorrect key hash from my certificate (the key hash you upload to your Facebook app's dev page). I wouldn't have thought the 32bit one would do it differently on a 64 bit machine, but as soon as I uploaded the new hash, Facebook login worked fine.

Comment: When I installed the 64 bit version and generated the key it was the same, so this did not work for me.